# Simple drawing with ASCII algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to draw a simple shapes in ASCII, when I try to draw a simple triangle, my last line is always omitted. Can you give me a hand? Maybe I am missing something?

```
static void set_char_at(char* mat, int cols, int x, int y, char c)
{
    mat[x*cols+y] = c;
}

int  test3()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char* mat = new char[(n*n)]; // newlines
    for(int i=0; i < n*n; i++) {
        mat[i] = ' ';
    }
    for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            set_char_at(mat, n, i, -j, '^');
        }
        set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '\n');
    }
    cout << mat;
}
```

EDIT: Input is 5, the desired output is:

```
     ^
    ^^
   ^^^
  ^^^^
 ^^^^^
```

In the right end of the screen as seen. I am missing the last line of "^".

Comment: What is you input, your actual output and your expected output ?

Comment: And why is this tagged C ? The source code is C++.

Comment: changed it , thanks

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger to see what's actually going on ?

Comment: On a semi-related note, why is `mat` allocated on the heap (and not `delete`d at the end)?

Comment: My desired output is a triangle drawn in most right, like a staircase algorithm, let`s say. If I have 3 as input, my triangle must be 
      ^
     ^^
    ^^^
like that, sorry for the formatting.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov you should edit the question to show the expected output, along with the inputs you are using and the actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* mat = new char[(n*n)]; // newlines
for(int i=0; i < n*n; i++)
    mat[i] = ' ';
```

Lets say that `n` is 1. The array, `mat`, will be size `1*1`. This can hold 1 character. In C++ a string (not a std::string) is an array of characters terminated by a nul-byte, which requires N+1 bytes.

```
char* mat = new char[(n*n) + 1];
for(int i=0; i < n*n; i++)
    mat[i] = ' ';
mat[n*n] = 0;
```

Back to your code, if `n` is 2:

```
for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
        set_char_at(mat, n, i, -j, '^');
    }
```

this will call:

```
        set_char_at(mat, n, 1, -0, '^');  => mat[1*2-0] => 2
        set_char_at(mat, n, 2, -0, '^');  => mat[2*2-0] => 4
        set_char_at(mat, n, 2, -1, '^');  => mat[2*2-1] => 3
```

Note the indexes on the right hand side, there's one more line in your loop:

```
for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
        set_char_at(mat, n, i, -j, '^');
    }
    set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '\n');
```

This translates to:

```
        set_char_at(mat, n, 1, -0, '^');  => mat[1*2-0] => 2
    set_char_at(mat, n, 1, 0, '\n');      => mat[1*2+0] => 2
        set_char_at(mat, n, 2, -0, '^');  => mat[2*2-0] => 4
        set_char_at(mat, n, 2, -1, '^');  => mat[2*2-1] => 3
    set_char_at(mat, n, 2, 0, '\n');      => mat[2*2+0] => 4
```

You need to allow room for carriage returns:

```
#include <iostream>

void testf(size_t n)
{
    const size_t matSize = (n+1) * n + 1;
    char* mat = new char[matSize] {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matSize - 1; ++i)
        mat[i] = ' ';
    mat[matSize - 1] = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
           mat[i*(n+1)+(n-j-1)] = '^';
       mat[i*(n+1) + n] = '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "--- start " << n << "\n";
    std::cout << mat;
    std::cout << "--- end\n";
}

int main()
{
    testf(4);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/mhY7iS

Comment: That`s one great explanation. Thanks, that solves that mystery I was in.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
```

You should use a less operator (<) here, as your x coordinate is from [0,n-1].

```
set_char_at(mat, n, i, -j, '^');
```

Your y cooridinate seems to be from [0,n-1] as well, so just -j is not
a good choice, perhaps you mean n-j?

```
set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '\n');
```

You probably want to add a n+1 th column for a line feed character (\n).

```
char* mat = new char[(n*n)]:
```

In this case you have to dimensionate for (n+1)*n instead of n*n.
Then x = n would be a valid argument.

```
cout << mat;
```

You use the character array as string. In this case you have to add a 0 as last character in the array. And you have to add one to the dimension, so it should look like

```
char* mat = new char[(n+1)*n + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting in this line `set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '\n');` the previous character "^". I mean, when j=0, you execute the line `set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '^');`, and later you execute `set_char_at(mat, n, i, 0, '\n');`

Comment: I saw that with the debugger. True. Maybe the bug is coming from there. Will report soon.